# Inserting data from spark to cassandra : how to verify everything is ok

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to insert data from a csv file into Cassandra using pyspark.

Here is the code :

I read the data :

```
    df =spark.read.format("csv") \
        .option("header","true") \
        .option("inferSchema","true") \
        .option("nullValue","NA") \
        .option("timestampFormat","ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss") \
        .option("quote", "\"") \
        .option("delimiter", ";") \
        .option("mode","failfast") \
        .load("gs://tidy-centaur-b1/data/PRESCRIPTIONS_ANO.csv")
```

Edit : i put the whole code to show the unique key

```
    dfi = df.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
        .withColumnRenamed("CHAIPRAT", "chaiprat") \
        .withColumnRenamed("PRE_PRE_DTD", "pre_pre_dtd") \
        .withColumnRenamed("NbMol", "nbmol") \
        .withColumnRenamed("NumAno", "numano")


    dfi.createOrReplaceTempView("prescription")
```

I count the rows and save the data into cassandra

```
    dfi.count()
    > 4169826

    dfi.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("confirm.truncate","true") \
        .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host","10.142.0.4") \
        .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042") \
        .option("keyspace","uasb03") \
        .option("table","prescription") \
        .save()
```

Now I read the data from cassandra and count the rows.

```
    presc = sql.read \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host","10.142.0.4") \
        .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042") \
        .load(table="prescription", keyspace="uasb03")

    presc.count()
    > 2148762
```

Only the half from the first counting.

I don't find anything in the log files that shows something went wrong.
Does anyone have a clue ?

Edit : I tried to change all the timeout values in cassandra.yaml but presc.count remains the same

Edit here is the cassandra table description

```
    cqlsh:uasb03> desc prescription;

    CREATE TABLE uasb03.prescription (
        id int PRIMARY KEY,
        chaiprat int,
        nbmol int,
        numano int,
        pre_pre_dtd timestamp
    ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
        AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

To perform my verification, I also wrote the output in a csv file and i got

```
    chaiprat;pre_pre_dtd;nbmol;numano;id
    29100476;03Feb2017:00:00:00;5;378369;8589934592
    29100476;24Feb2017:00:00:00;1;378369;8589934593
    29100476;27Feb2017:00:00:00;2;378369;8589934594
```

the id is bigger than an int.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in your CSV input?

Comment: in fact there are indirectly :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable cause for this is that your data don't have really unique row identifier that could become the partition key, so when you're store the data, some values are overwritten. You can fix this by explicitly creating the table with correct partition key & clustering columns before saving the data. This could be done via `createCassandraTable` call on your data frame (see [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-a-new-cassandra-table-from-a-dataset-schema)), something like this:

```
createCassandraTable(
  "uasb03", "prescription", 
  partitionKeyColumns = Some(Seq("columnA")), 
  clusteringKeyColumns = Some(Seq("columnB")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your clue. In fact, it thought i had a unique key in my table (i didn't put all the code but i add dfi = df.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())



But the id column was defined as an int and the generated ids were too big so i'll try with bigint. It should work.

Comment: But is it selected as primary key in your table? What `describe table ...` shows?

Comment: It is.. I updated my question to be more complete but I think the problem comes from the size of the int used for id and the one generated by monotonically_increasing_id. Thanks everybody for pointing me the problem.

Comment: Can you run countDistinct on the id column?

Comment: It works now. It was my id defined as an int in the cassandra table that couldn't hold the bigint generated in spark. Thank you all